# Docker swarm manager

Tags: docker-swarm

В общем - имеем 4 машины. 3 manager и 1 workser все машины объедены в docker swarm.
Все 4 машины добавлены в NO_PROXY т.к. в нашей компании соединение идет через порокси. Разворачиваем обычный redis в одной реплике. Естественно создаётся network overlay на всех машинах, но когда пытаешься получить доступ к redis, он присутствует только на одной машине -> там где он развернут, но, как я понимаю, доступ к redis должен быть на всех, как минимум manager, машинах.

Почему нет доступа на остальных машинах?

Файл развертывания redis-

```
version: "3.1"
services:
        redis:
            image: redis:alpine
            restart: always
            ports:
                    - "6379:6379"
            deploy:
                    restart_policy:
                            condition: on-failure
            networks:
                    -  redis_network
networks:
    redis_network:
            external: true
```

команда для создания сети

```
docker network create -d overlay redis_network
```

команда для создания сервиса

```
docker stack deploy -c мой_вышеупомянутый_файл redis
```

Все порты открыты